# How to check if returned value is array before using it?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I have this function:

```
//get mgs by orderID
function getOrderMsgs($orderId){
    global $conn;
    $query = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM msgs ";
    $query .= "WHERE orderid=" . $orderId . " ";
    $msgset = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    confirm_query($msgset);
    while ($msg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($msgset)){
        $return[] = $msg;
    } 
    return $return;
}
```

That returns all messages with a certain message Id. Now what I need to do is check if the returned value is indeed an array since after the query we may find no messages with that specific Id which I believe won't return an array. So far this is what I have:

```
$msgId = sql_prep($_GET['oid']);
$order = getOrderById($msgId);
$msgs=getOrderMsgs($msgId);
echo '<h2>Order #'.$order['orderid'].': '.$order['title'].'</h2>';
echo '<h3>Message thread</h3>';
foreach($msgs as $msg){
    echo $msg['msg'].'<br>'.$msg['sender'].'<br>'.$msg['timestamp'].'<br><br>';
}
```

And it returns an error if there is no msgs with that id in db.

Comment: have you tried googling for `is_array`?

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about that function. It just saved my life.

Answer (score 0):

To see type of a variable you can use `gettype`

```
    print_r(gettype($_COOKIE));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you initialize `$return` before using it. This ensures you are always returning an array.

```
function getOrderMsgs($orderId){
    global $conn;
    $return = array(); // initialize variable

    $query = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM msgs ";
    $query .= "WHERE orderid=" . $orderId . " ";
    $msgset = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    confirm_query($msgset);
    while ($msg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($msgset)){
        $return[] = $msg;
    } 
    return $return;
}
```

In you code you can then inspect the array and use the number of array elements to decide what to do next.

```
$order = getOrderById($msgId);
if(count($order) > 0) {
  // Found something
} else {
  // Nothing found
}
```